RayLib and linking a statically compiled library (C)
I have been trying to use the RayLib C library to play sounds. The overall goal is to make an audio waveform visualizer. I'm knowledgable in C and C# coding, but only using the standard libraries. I have a mockup of my file structure below.
To build the library, I followed the instructions on RayLib's Readme (cd'd into src, ran make). That leaves me with raylib.a and raylib.h in the src folder, along with many other source and header files. I am using CLion, which uses CMake to build the project. This is what my current CMakeLists.txt file looks like:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(Audio_visualizer C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(Audio_visualizer main.c)
include_directories (Audio_visualizer PUBLIC /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src)

Again, there is a rough diagram of my file structure below. When clang invokes the linker command, the linker fails with the following error output:
FAILED: Audio_visualizer 
: && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/Audio_visualizer.dir/main.c.o -o Audio_visualizer   && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
     "_InitAudioDevice", referenced from:
        _main in main.c.o
    "_LoadSound", referenced from:
        _main in main.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

I am programming on an Apple M1 Mac Air, which follows the Arm64 architecture. Does anyone know of some possible solutions to this problem? Any help is appreciated.
I have already tried to use the precompiled MacOS RayLib library, using include_directories (Audio_visualizer PUBLIC /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0_macos/include) instead of include_directories (Audio_visualizer PUBLIC /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src). The linker failed with the same error. I have made sure all my files are saved and that the CMake config is updated between builds.
Here's my file structure. There's obviously some files excluded, but I don't think their locations are important. Please ask me it would be helpful to see them:
-Projects
-Audio_visualizer
-CMakeLists.txt
-main.c
-sounds
-fart-with-reverb.mp3
-Libraries
-raylib-5.0
-src
-libraylib.a
-Makefile
-raylib.h
-raymath.h


UPDATE
I've made some revisions to my setup, and I'm receiving a different error now. I have linked the libraries I need using target_link_libraries, and now I am receiving the following error:
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Audio_visualizer/cmake-build-debug
[1/1] Linking C executable Audio_visualizer
FAILED: Audio_visualizer 
: && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/Audio_visualizer.dir/main.c.o -o Audio_visualizer  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/raylib.h  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/raymath.h  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/rlgl.h  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/raudio.c  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/rcore.c  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/rglfw.c  /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/libraylib.a && :
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

I suspect that the compiler is interpreting the libraries to be linked as output names.
This is how my CMakeLists.txt file looks:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(Audio_visualizer C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(Audio_visualizer main.c)
target_include_directories (Audio_visualizer PUBLIC /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src)
target_link_libraries(Audio_visualizer
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/raylib.h
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/raymath.h
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/rlgl.h
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/raudio.c
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/rcore.c
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/rglfw.c
        /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/libraylib.a)


Your CMakeLists.txt actually don't link with anything. You need to add a target_link_libraries command to link with the libraries.

If I included the line link_libraries(Audio_visualizer /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src), would that work? Or is that malformatted?

Aha! I added that line to my CMakeLists.txt. I'm going to work through this problem a little more, as I understand more of what to do.

It seems you're a beginner at C. A header or source file is not the same as a library. You should link only with the libraries, not the header or source files. Remove everything from your target_link_libraries command except /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/libraylib.a.

I removed all but the /Users/1000714/CLionProjects/Libraries/raylib-5.0/src/libraylib.a, and I receive errors in the linker that it cannot find methods. The error I got is:
"_objc_enumerationMutation", referenced from:
__glfwPollMonitorsCocoa in libraylib.a(rglfw.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
There are many more lines of the error, but they're all similar. These errors do not occur when I include the header and source files in the target_link_librariescommand.
